# Animate UIView on touchesEnded event

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, duration, touches

I am trying to animate a `UIView` (block-based animation) but I cannot make the timing work (duration, etc.). The animation runs, because the changes are done, and the completition output message is shown, but it just ignores the duration and instantly makes the changes.

I asume there is something wrong with the way I am doing things, but I just cannot figure out where the mistake is. Let me explain what I am trying to do:

I have a `UIViewController` (viewcontroller) that handles two objects (view1 and view2) of a `UIView` sublcass in which I have defined the `touchesEnded` method.

The idea is that when view1 has been touched, I want to animate view2. So what I did was to implement an animation method in the `UIView` subclass, a notification in the `touchesEnded` method (also in the `UIView` subclass), and
a trigger method in the controller that would call the animation of the second view. Something like this:

```
// In the UIView subclass:
- (void) myAnimation{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
        delay:0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
        animations:^{
            self.alpha = 0.5;
        } 
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            NSLog(@"Done!");
        }];
}

// In the UIView subclass:
- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet*) touches withEvent: (UIEvent*) event {
        [pParent viewHasBeenTouched];   // pParent is a reference to the controller
}

// In the UIViewController:
- (void) viewHasBeenTouched {
    [view2 myAnimation];
}
```

(The animation and work flow is in fact a bit more complex, but this simple example just fails to work)

If I place the animation somewhere else, it may work, for example just after initializing the views in the init method of the controller. But if I try to do this forward-backward calls, the animation will just ignore the duration and execute in one step.

Any ideas? What have I missed about touches and gestures that I should know? Thank you.

NEW INFORMATION ADDED TO THE ORIGINAL POST:

The AppDelegate does nothing but this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The TestViewControler.h is just this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TestView.h"

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController{
    TestView* myView;
}

- (void) viewHasBeenTouched;

@end
```

and the viewDidLoad only does this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myView = [[TestView alloc] initWithParent:self];
    [self.view addSubview:myView]; 
}
```

Finally, the UIView has a TestView.h which looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TestViewController; // Forward declaration
@interface TestView : UIView{
    TestViewController* pParent;
}

- (id)initWithParent:(TestViewController*) parent;
- (void) myAnimation;

@end
```

And the init method used is:

```
- (id)initWithParent:(TestViewController *)parent{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50, 20, 100, 200);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) pParent = parent;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return self;
}
```

So... with this simple code I posted, the error occurs. As I said, the animation does change the alpha, but with no delay or timing. It's just instantaneous. Any ideas with this added information?

Thank you again for the help.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a project and changed "this.alpha" to "self.alpha" (what is your "this" anyway?) and it works just fine.

Comment: I misspelled `self` for `this`, sorry (c++ heritage).

Comment: I have tried an example as simple as I posted but it does not work. I edit the original post and add some more information about the ViewController to see if the error is there. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Again I pasted your code into my project and it works fine. Could you create a new project and insert what you posted here and report.

BTW:
Do you have any warnings? What device are you working on? What compiler are you using? What SDK are you using?...

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I want to apologize first for all the people how have studied my problem and have lost valuable time on it.

All the second part I posted in the original question was copy and pasted indeed, it was the first part that had those two mismatching errors because they came from a more complex code. And that code works without problem as you have all stated. The problem is that I did not copy and paste a method that I thought I had removed from the project (and which is called at the start of the application):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // ... More code
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    // ... More code
    return YES;
}
```

It obviously needs no further explanation.

Again thank you very much for your time, and my sincere apologizes.